# Use flexbox to align a search bar

Tags: html, css, flexbox, nav, searchbar

I'm working on an assignment to clone the npm website using html and css.

Here is what the search bar is supposed to look like:

[image: search bar]

Here is the [link](https://codepen.io/mikaylac97/pen/eYpLXrj) to the full code.

```css
.npm-logo {
  width: 85px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.magnifying-glass {
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 150px;
}

.search-input {
  height: 20px;
  width: 1100px;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 40px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border: 0px;
}

.search-button {
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #FB3E44;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

.gray-border {
  border: 1px gray solid;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
}

.flex-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="search-bar">

  <img class="npm-logo" src="https://i.imgur.com/BH7CCkO.png" alt="npmlogo" />

  <div class="flex-wrap">
    <img class="magnifying-glass" src="https://i.imgur.com/lrQiTER.png" alt="magnifying glass image" />

    <form action=“” class=“form”>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search packages" class="search-input">
      <input type="button" value="Search" class="search-button" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#" class="link gray-border">Join</a>
<a href="#" class="link join-log-btn">Log in</a>
</div>
```

Clearly I am very new to webdev and really need some help. I know that I'm probably supposed to use flexbox to get the search button and magnifying glass aligned with the bar itself. I also need to get the Log in button to read on the same line.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I only focused about the search bar, I took the liberty to clean up the code a bit and remove any unnecessary lines of code, i tried to keep it as simple as possible for you to understand everything  https://jsfiddle.net/zd8y46mg/

Answer (score 1):

There is minimal change on the HTML code. Only remove the magnifying-glass image. The magnifying glass has restructured to put as the background of the search input. Most changes are from the CSS. Below are the few changes:

1. The magnifying glass icon set as the background of `.search-input`.

```
.search-input {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/lrQiTER.png) no-repeat 1%;
  background-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
```

2. The search input width has changed to 100% for the responsive width purpose.

```
.search-input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

3. Add CSS for flex support on `.form`.

```
.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 260px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

4. Add nowrap configuration for `.join-log-btn`.

```
.join-log-btn {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

5. Add flex-nowrap configuration for the `#search-bar`.

```
    #search-bar {
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }
```

6. Add flex-shrink to `.search-button`

```
.search-button {
      flex-shrink: 0;
```

Link to [codepen](https://codepen.io/yinsweet/pen/QWjZjZq).

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins');
body {
  font-family: 'Poppins';
}

header>div {
  padding: 0 25px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}

nav {
  width: 600px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.blackHeart {
  width: 20px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

#search-bar {
  padding: 5px 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.npm-logo {
  width: 85px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 260px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}


/*
.magnifying-glass {
    width: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
}
*/

.search-input {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 40px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border: 0px;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/lrQiTER.png) no-repeat 1%;
  background-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.search-button {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #FB3E44;
  color: white;
  padding: 0px;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: gray;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

.gray-border {
  border: 1px gray solid;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
}

.join-log-btn {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  <div>
    <div>
      <img class="blackHeart" src="https://i.imgur.com/LN4RJko.png" alt="black heart" />
      <span> Nifty Penguin Magic </span>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"> npm Enterprise </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Products </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Solutions </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Resources </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Docs </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Support </a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>


  <div id="search-bar">

    <img class="npm-logo" src="https://i.imgur.com/BH7CCkO.png" alt="npmlogo" />

    <!--<img class="magnifying-glass" src="https://i.imgur.com/lrQiTER.png" alt="magnifying glass image"/>
     -->

    <form action="" class="form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search packages" class="search-input">
      <input type="button" value="Search" class="search-button" />
    </form>

    <a href="#" class="link gray-border">Join</a>
    <a href="#" class="link join-log-btn">Log in</a>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</header>

<section id="intro"></section>

<h1>Build amazing things</h1>
<p>Essential JavaScript development tools that help you go to market faster and build powerful applications using modern open source code. </p>
<a href="#">See plans Join for free</a>

<section id="geninfo"></section>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100.79 90.68"><defs><style>.cls-1{isolation:isolate;}.cls-2{opacity:0.8;mix-blend-mode:luminosity;}.cls-3,.cls-4,.cls-5,.cls-6{stroke:#c18752;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:0.27px;}.cls-3,.cls-6{opacity:0.3;}.cls-3{fill:url(#Orange_2);}.cls-4,.cls-5{opacity:0.2;}.cls-4{fill:url(#Orange_2-2);}.cls-5{fill:url(#Orange_2-3);}.cls-6{fill:url(#Orange_2-4);}</style><linearGradient id="Orange_2" x1="-1973.93" y1="-513.04" x2="-1932.27" y2="-513.04" gradientTransform="translate(1966.33 -514.02) rotate(-30.81)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#e3bca9"/><stop offset="0.5" stop-color="#d8a089"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#cf8c72"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="Orange_2-2" x1="-1973.59" y1="-528.66" x2="-1890.35" y2="-528.66" xlink:href="#Orange_2"/><linearGradient id="Orange_2-3" x1="-1973.59" y1="-473.16" x2="-1890.35" y2="-473.16" xlink:href="#Orange_2"/><linearGradient id="Orange_2-4" x1="-1931.88" y1="-488.65" x2="-1890.22" y2="-488.65" xlink:href="#Orange_2"/></defs><title>best-open</title><g class="cls-1"><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_2-2" data-name="Layer 2"><g class="cls-2"><polygon class="cls-3" points="52.05 48.55 28.59 90.54 0.14 42.84 23.6 0.85 52.05 48.55"/><polygon class="cls-4" points="48.58 42.09 0.48 42.77 23.89 0.82 71.98 0.14 48.58 42.09"/><polygon class="cls-5" points="77.01 89.76 28.91 90.44 52.31 48.48 100.41 47.81 77.01 89.76"/><polygon class="cls-6" points="100.65 47.96 77.19 89.95 48.74 42.25 72.2 0.26 100.65 47.96"/></g></g></g></g></svg>

<h1>Bring the best of open source to your company</h1>
<p>npm is the tool used by over 11,000,000 JavaScript developers around the world. Your developers already use it. Your company depends on it. Create an Org and get more out of the tools your team already knows and loves.</p>

<section id="createorg"></section>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 25.99 21.21"><title>zero-configuration</title><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_2-2" data-name="Layer 2"><path d="M23,19.36l-3.79-4.59L22.58,14a.55.55,0,0,0,.43-.5.54.54,0,0,0-.33-.56L13.47,8.84a.56.56,0,0,0-.59.08.59.59,0,0,0-.19.56L15,19.3a.59.59,0,0,0,.5.44A.57.57,0,0,0,16,19.4l1.41-3.19,3.79,4.59A1.13,1.13,0,0,0,23,19.36Z"/><path d="M2.14,11.32A2.14,2.14,0,0,1,0,9.18v-7A2.14,2.14,0,0,1,2.14,0H23.85A2.14,2.14,0,0,1,26,2.14v7a2.14,2.14,0,0,1-1.66,2.09l-2.11-.71h1.63a1.38,1.38,0,0,0,1.38-1.38v-7A1.38,1.38,0,0,0,23.85.76H2.14A1.38,1.38,0,0,0,.76,2.14v7a1.38,1.38,0,0,0,1.38,1.38h8.55l.26.76Z"/></g></g></svg>

<h1>Zero configuration</h1>
<p>Create an org, add your team, and start collaborating. Nothing to configure, set up, or manage.</p>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 29.4 27.38"><title>team-management</title><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_2-2" data-name="Layer 2"><path d="M14.75,5.21c-3.45,0-3.36-5.4.11-5.2C18.14.19,18,5.21,14.75,5.21Zm-.06-.89h.25l.22,0,.2-.06A1.68,1.68,0,0,0,15.73,4h0a2.73,2.73,0,0,0,.35-.33,1.87,1.87,0,0,0,.33-.75,1.88,1.88,0,0,0,0-.58h0a2.42,2.42,0,0,0-.1-.36,2.82,2.82,0,0,0-.21-.38L16,1.5a2.85,2.85,0,0,0-.25-.25A2,2,0,0,0,15.4,1,1.7,1.7,0,0,0,14.81.9h-.27l-.06.22,0-.22a1.78,1.78,0,0,0-.54.17,2.26,2.26,0,0,0-.26.16,1.38,1.38,0,0,0-.3.29l.11.2-.13-.18a1.83,1.83,0,0,0-.23.38,2,2,0,0,0-.12.42,2,2,0,0,0,0,.49,2,2,0,0,0,.11.42,2.64,2.64,0,0,0,.2.37l.08.09a2.21,2.21,0,0,0,.26.24,1.8,1.8,0,0,0,.35.21l.05,0h0A1.38,1.38,0,0,0,14.69,4.32Z"/><path d="M11.73,10.05c-1.69,0-1.49-2.32-1.32-3.49a3.07,3.07,0,0,1,1.18-2c.69-.48,1.28.31.57.7a2.6,2.6,0,0,0-.38.36l.12.1v.1l-.14-.16a2.28,2.28,0,0,0-.44,1l0,.2c0,.65,0,1.3,0,1.94l0,.13h0l0,0h0l.09.11.08,0,0-.11.1-.08,0,.21.13,0h6.08l.13,0,.08,0h0l.05,0L18.08,9l0,0h0l0-.07,0-.12a20,20,0,0,0,0-2h0A4.74,4.74,0,0,0,18,6.15a3.17,3.17,0,0,0-.27-.47l-.14.1.09-.17c-.18-.22-.68-.49-.74-.77-.12-.55.41-.6.77-.42a3.15,3.15,0,0,1,1.35,2.81c0,1.24.16,2.71-1.45,2.82C15.67,10.19,13.68,10.05,11.73,10.05Z"/><path d="M4.45,22.48c-3.46,0-3.36-5.41.11-5.21C7.84,17.45,7.7,22.48,4.45,22.48Zm0-.9h.24a2.17,2.17,0,0,0,.42-.11,2,2,0,0,0,.72-.54,1.7,1.7,0,0,0,.33-1.33h0a2.42,2.42,0,0,0-.1-.36,2.82,2.82,0,0,0-.21-.38l-.08-.09a2.85,2.85,0,0,0-.25-.25,2,2,0,0,0-.37-.21,2,2,0,0,0-.42-.12l-.17,0H4.23l-.05.22,0-.22a1.7,1.7,0,0,0-.54.17,2.26,2.26,0,0,0-.26.16,2.13,2.13,0,0,0-.31.29l.12.2-.13-.18a2.14,2.14,0,0,0-.23.38,2,2,0,0,0-.12.42,2.68,2.68,0,0,0,0,.49,2.9,2.9,0,0,0,.12.42,2.08,2.08,0,0,0,.2.36l0,0v0h0l0,.05.25.25a2.38,2.38,0,0,0,.41.23h0a2.54,2.54,0,0,0,.37.1H4.4Z"/><path d="M1.43,27.31C-.26,27.31-.06,25,.11,23.82a3,3,0,0,1,1.18-2c.69-.48,1.28.32.57.7a2.22,2.22,0,0,0-.38.37l.12.09V23l-.14-.16a2.55,2.55,0,0,0-.3.5,4.28,4.28,0,0,0-.15.51l0,.21V26l0,.14H1l.12.15,0,0v0l.11,0H7.45l.14,0,.11-.05.08-.07,0-.05h0l0-.07,0-.12a20,20,0,0,0,0-2.05h0a2.73,2.73,0,0,0-.15-.56,2.42,2.42,0,0,0-.26-.47L7.3,23l.11-.14c-.18-.22-.7-.51-.76-.8-.14-.67.55-.57.89-.33a3.14,3.14,0,0,1,1.22,2.52c.06,1.26.23,2.9-1.42,3C5.39,27.46,3.38,27.31,1.43,27.31Z"/><path d="M25.05,22.48c-3.45,0-3.36-5.41.11-5.21C28.44,17.45,28.3,22.48,25.05,22.48Zm-.05-.9h.24a2.17,2.17,0,0,0,.42-.11l.2-.1.18-.11h0a3.51,3.51,0,0,0,.34-.33,1.88,1.88,0,0,0,.21-.36h0a2.78,2.78,0,0,0,.12-.38l-.17,0h.18l-.1,0,.1,0a1.6,1.6,0,0,0,0-.49h0a2.12,2.12,0,0,0-.1-.36,2.82,2.82,0,0,0-.21-.38l-.08-.1-.25-.24a2,2,0,0,0-.37-.21,2,2,0,0,0-.42-.12l-.17,0h-.27l-.06.22,0-.22a1.78,1.78,0,0,0-.54.17,2.26,2.26,0,0,0-.26.16,2.06,2.06,0,0,0-.3.29l.11.2-.13-.18a2.14,2.14,0,0,0-.23.38,1.67,1.67,0,0,0-.12.91,2,2,0,0,0,.11.42,1.75,1.75,0,0,0,.29.47l.25.24a2,2,0,0,0,.35.2l.05,0h0a2.09,2.09,0,0,0,.43.11H25Z"/><path d="M22,27.31c-1.69,0-1.49-2.32-1.32-3.49a3.07,3.07,0,0,1,1.18-2c.69-.48,1.28.32.57.7a2.65,2.65,0,0,0-.38.37l.12.09V23l-.14-.16a3.1,3.1,0,0,0-.29.5,2.29,2.29,0,0,0-.15.51l0,.21V26l0,.14h0l.11.15,0,0v0l.11,0h6.19l.14,0,.12-.05.07-.07,0-.05h0l0-.07,0-.12a20,20,0,0,0,0-2.05h0a5.12,5.12,0,0,0-.15-.56,4.31,4.31,0,0,0-.26-.47l-.15.1L28,22.9c-.19-.22-.71-.51-.77-.8-.14-.67.55-.56.9-.33a3.17,3.17,0,0,1,1.22,2.52c.05,1.26.22,2.9-1.43,3C26,27.46,24,27.31,22,27.31Z"/><path d="M14.74,17.46c-.79,0-.45-2.4-.45-2.84s-.33-2.85.45-2.83.45,2.29.45,2.74S15.53,17.46,14.74,17.46Z"/><path d="M10.6,19.84c-.78,0-.34-.73,0-1s.95-.55,1.42-.82l1.71-1c.24-.14.69-.53,1-.51.74.05.38.69,0,.94a13.26,13.26,0,0,1-1.37.8l-1.79,1c-.26.15-.68.51-1,.51Z"/><path d="M18.87,19.84c-.33,0-.74-.36-1-.51l-1.71-1c-.47-.27-1-.51-1.42-.82s-.76-.92,0-1c.29,0,.71.34.93.47l1.69,1c.5.28,1,.54,1.51.86S19.67,19.84,18.87,19.84Z"/></g></g></svg>

<h1>Team management</h1>
<p>Control who has access to what modules within your team namespace using straightforward team management capabilities.</p>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 29.59 22.75"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}</style></defs><title>feature-parity</title><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_2-2" data-name="Layer 2"><path class="cls-1" d="M29.59,16.62H0"/><rect x="0.31" width="11.93" height="6.88" rx="2.42"/><rect x="0.31" y="8" width="11.93" height="6.88" rx="2.42"/><rect x="16.35" width="11.93" height="6.88" rx="2.42"/><rect x="16.35" y="8" width="11.93" height="6.88" rx="2.42"/><polyline points="14.47 19.04 15.9 21.37 16.75 22.75 12.2 22.75 14.48 19.04"/></g></g></svg>

<h1>Familiar features</h1>
<p>npm Orgs has 100% parity with all the public npm registry features your developers already use. </p>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 26.98 21.26"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill-rule:evenodd;}</style></defs><title>npm-audit</title><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_2-2" data-name="Layer 2"><path d="M0,15.53V5.81a5.82,5.82,0,0,1,11.63-.08h3.81A5.77,5.77,0,1,1,27,5.81v9.72a5.77,5.77,0,0,1-11.54,0V11.89H11.63v3.64A5.82,5.82,0,0,1,0,15.53Zm16.74-.09A4.52,4.52,0,0,0,21.17,20a4.38,4.38,0,0,0,4.42-4.42,4.11,4.11,0,0,0-1.3-3.12,4.38,4.38,0,0,0-6.24,0,4.62,4.62,0,0,0-1.31,3Zm-15.35,0a4.43,4.43,0,1,0,8.85.09,4.15,4.15,0,0,0-1.3-3.12,4.39,4.39,0,0,0-6.25,0,4.25,4.25,0,0,0-1.3,3Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M6.94,12.06c1.82.78,3.21,2.69,1.82,4.51Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M22.56,12.06c1.82.78,3.21,2.69,1.82,4.51Z"/></g></g></svg>

<h1>npm audit</h1>
<p>Enjoy the security auditing features built into the npm client, a zero-friction way to make open source software safer. </p>

<a href="#">Create an Org</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello when uou want to center an image in a block or inline-block element, you have to place place it as a child of your element.
Your parent element get position relative and this image has absolute position (in left top corner) after this you have to play with margin, padding, width ...

Another advice is to use % or vw in html to set a width and height

Answer (score 0):

Remove the long fixed width from the search input (`.search-input`). It's causing an overflow. That's unnecessary.

```
.search-input {
  height: 20px;
  /* width: 1100px; */
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 40px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border: 0px;
}
```

Instead, use flex on the form so that the children can consume free space.

```
.form {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
```

Move the magnifying glass (`.magnifying-glass`) into the form container, so that it can be absolutely positioned relative to the form, not the search bar.

```
.magnifying-glass {
   width: 20px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 10px;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

This will add some space between elements:

```
#search-bar > * + *,
  .form > * + * {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/678789asdflu/pen/XWmxbvz)

Comment: small change in .search-input , color should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Please, follow the code snippet below for the desired result:

**NOTE:** Have linked Fontawesome's CSS for using search icon as -
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

```html
  <div class="search-menu">
    <div class="npm-logo">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/BH7CCkO.png" alt="npmlogo" />
    </div>

    <div class="search-bar">
      <label id="search-label" for="search">
        <i class="fa fa-search magnifying-glass"></i>
      </label>
      <input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search Packages">
      <button>
        Search
      </button>
    </div>

    <a class="join" href="#">Join</a>
    <a class="log-in" href="#">Log In</a>
  </div>
```

```css
.search-menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1em 2em;
}

.npm-logo {
  width: 10%;
}

.npm-logo > img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.search-bar {
  display: flex;
  width: 70%;
}

.search-bar > label {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  width: 5%;
}

.magnifying-glass {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.search-bar > input[type="text"] {
  margin: 0;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 40px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0.2em;
}

.search-bar > button {
  border: none;
  background-color: #fb3e44;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
}

.join,
.log-in {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**Have few suggestions after reviewing your code:**

1. Should not put a **fixed width** on an element. Giving **fixed width** takes the default responsiveness of the web page away. To maintain the responsiveness of the web page, should always prefer to give **width in percentages**.
2. Should avoid specifying **height** for any element. If you want the benefits of height, try using **padding** instead.
3. Should apply `max-width: 100%;` on images to make them responsive.